# How to pass variable length float array to GPUImageFilter Shader?

Tags: arrays, variables, gpuimage

I want to pass my touch points to GPUImage (iOS)
The Point can be translate to float array, the length of the array is variable length.
But I must direct the length of array in shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: not a glsl expert

AFAIk you can't have variable length arrays like what you want. This is a GLSL limitation, not GPUImage so it's not a quick fix- the work you'll be doing will be with textures or glsl, not GPUImage.

Here's another stack overflow post about glsl: [GLSL indexing into uniform array with variable length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868781/glsl-indexing-into-uniform-array-with-variable-length)

There's two solutions that could work:

1) Limit the number of points. It's reasonable to limit touches but in practice may be hard to narrow them down if there's too many. You could pass these points in to a fixed length array or as individual constants (one for each point). If you really care about scalability with the number of points this isn't a great method because in your shader you'll have to do check each of these points and perform the relevant computation, which could be expensive when performed for the entire image (again, depending on your use case). If for each pixel you're checking a distance to point, this could be too expensive.

2) Input your points in a texture. You can either have 2 1D textures with the x&y coordinates and then treat them like an array (then go to option 1), or you can create a 2D texture, all 0, and set parts to 1 where there are touches. The 2D texture can have a lower resolution than the actual screen. This method could be a lot less work for the shader if you're doing something simple like turning finger touches black.

Your choice depends largely on what you're doing with the points in the shader.